# How To Include Checkboxes for Specific TreeView Nodes?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am trying to create parent and child tree nodes like the following but want CheckBoxes to be displayed only for the nodes indicated with (CheckBox). If I set the CheckBoxes property of the TreeView control to true it shows CheckBoxes for all TreeView nodes.

```
-> Parent Node 1 (No Checkbox)
----> Child Node of Parent 1 (No Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 1 of Child Node of Parent 1 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 2 of Child Node of Parent 1 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 3 of Child Node of Parent 1 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 4 of Child Node of Parent 1 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 5 of Child Node of Parent 1 (Checkbox)

-> Parent Node 2 (No Checkbox)
----> Child Node of Parent 2 (No Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 1 of Child Node of Parent 2 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 2 of Child Node of Parent 2 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 3 of Child Node of Parent 2 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 4 of Child Node of Parent 2 (Checkbox)
--------> Subnode 5 of Child Node of Parent 2 (Checkbox)
```

Comment: Which TreeView control (both Windows Forms and WPF have a control named TreeView - there may be others too). Is your rule *"checkboxes only on leaf nodes"*?

Comment: Windows Forms. Not sure what leaf nodes are but probably answer is yes.

Comment: You should tag your question with Windows Form. The XAML in the answer below (about `HierarchicalDataTemplate`) is about WPF. A tree has branches. Each branch can have other branches or leaves. But a leaf can't have anything branch from it. A leaf node has no child nodes

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` tag to create custom datatemplates for each level of your `TreeView`.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:Parent}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:child}" ItemsSource="{Binding subnodes}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```